# How to retrieve last part of given path?

Tags: php, string

I'm writing directory listings and want to get the name of the last directory.

Example:

```
/data/henry/files/gallery
```

I only want to get the last directory which is **gallery**.

I tried with `substr('abcdef', 1)` but it's static.

I have an idea of storing the directories into array and then retrieve the last value but how can I do that?

EDIT:

Thanks @deceze for the easy solution.

My solution was longer and not recommended:

```
$dirarray = explode("/",$row['source']);
$total = count($dirarray);
$sharename = $dirarray[($total-1)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo basename('/data/henry/files/gallery');
```

http://php.net/basename

Comment: Wow that was sooo easyy! Thank you!

Comment: I found other solution but it's long;

Comment: This is how you _should_ do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expression? Assuming your text is in `$text` variable:

```
preg_match_all("|(/[a-z]+)$|", $text, $result);
```

`$result` will contain `/gallery`.

Comment: This will not work, after correcting typos it still does not work with `/foo/bar-baz` or `/hello/from/pcre_world`

Comment: edited to format correctly and fix missing quote mark. But `basename()` is still a better answer. PHP has a lot of functions for these kinds of common operations; don't always assume you have to do it yourself.