# What is the term for the last part of the path of a URL

Tags: url, web

What term do you give the part of the url after the last slash, but before the query?  It seems most places people call it "the last part of the path" e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274209/how-to-retrieve-last-part-of-given-path) but that is just so... wordy.

E.g. "something" in this url:

http://www.example.com/path/to/something?param=foo

**Update:**

I was hoping there was a well-known answer that I was not aware of, but it seems there is still some debate so, that's my answer right there.  Guess I'll just keep calling it "the part of the path after the last slash".  But I'll leave this question open anway, in case someone makes a convincing argument that gets lots of upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit late to the party, but where I work we call it the slug, as mentioned here for example: https://prettylinks.com/2018/03/url-slugs/

Comment: Please edit relevant parts of your link into your answer.

Comment: The relevant part is that it's called a slug. I can't speak for the OP but this was precisely the answer to the question I came here with. It was exactly the word I was looking for to name my little react hook, useSlug()

Comment: To add some credibility and popularity to "slug", this Wikipedia article on Clean URLs defines the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL

Answer (score 5):

protocol://server.domain/path?query

The path element (and it appears there is no 'defacto' definition) in my mind is the path to the resource on the server. No matter whether the resource is a file (blah.html) or a folder (/path/) it still instructs the server to use the path to find the resource.

Now there appears to be another definition at good/bad ol' Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) which states that it is usually "http://server/path/program?query_string" where the end resource is defined as 'program' but I think this is incorrect (is a folder a program?)

So.. perhaps its should be

```
protocol://server.domain/path[/resource.*]?query
```

? /../../ I traverse...

Comment: Might be succinct to summarize this as it being a "resource"

Answer (score 3):

If URL is like /path/to/file.html or example.com/path/to/**something.php**?param=foo

then I think we can call it **filename** as mentioned at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html

Comment: +1 Although it is a silly distinction to differentiate between the file name and the path as a whole since not all web requests resolve to files.

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes I know, not all the web request resolves to files, that's the reason I was a little restrictive to call it filename.

Comment: I'm conflicted as to which of the two answers is correct.  Technically @Paul's is right from the perspective of the standard, but your link to the Apache documentation clearly states your point.  Certainly when it comes to understanding how a file becomes a URL your answer is the most helpful.

Comment: I think the line is blurry over here. On some type of servers those files really exist and on the same paths. But as the technology has evolved I think all of the things after the domain name has just became some type of identifier as a whole.

Comment: regardless of whether the path resolves to a file it is still a path. If there is no resource at the end i.e. mydoc.pdf then the resource is the folder... either way it is still a path (to a resource)

Comment: @PaulSullivan As it is argued in your answer, that "path" is not the path in literal sense and is just an instruction to server to find the resource. And I also believe thats true. Then can we call "filename" the last part "path"? whether or not it actually resolves to a filename or not.

Comment: @AamirAbro - I believe it should just be 'path' (abbreviation of 'path to resource')

Comment: I always call it the 'basename'

Answer (score 1):

I found the terms "last segment" or "last chunk" quite accurate and succinct.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is called a query string whenever it is instructing action on the website. Code is frequently written to address the query string, which would prompt customized results on the page.

Otherwise, I agree it would be called a file name, if the path was referencing a file.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few uncertain suggestions here and there, including "filename", "basename". The Qt project has these names in their lexicon, so it can serve as a standard.

Namely check out the [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html) class.

They have standardized the names as the following:

```
QFileInfo fi("/tmp/archive.tar.gz");

fi.fileName();         // "archive.tar.gz"
fi.baseName();         // "archive"
fi.completeBaseName(); // "archive.tar"
fi.suffix();           // "gz"
fi.completeSuffix();   // "tar.gz"
```

This is a specification for local files however, so in this standard, there is a departure from basic `URI` terminology here:

```
fi.path();             // "/tmp"
fi.filePath();         // "/tmp/archive.tar.gz"
```

---

Where as in [QUrl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html), you have `path` & `fileName`

```
QUrl("file:file.txt").path();                   // "file.txt"
QUrl("/home/user/file.txt").path();             // "/home/user/file.txt"
QUrl("http://www.example.com/test/123").path(); // "/test/123"
```

and

```
QUrl("file:file.txt").fileName();                   // "file.txt"
QUrl("/home/user/file.txt").fileName();             // "file.txt"
QUrl("http://www.example.com/test/123").fileName(); // "123"
```

---

If I were building a library, I personally would adopt `QFileInfo` terminology and apply to both `URI` and local files, and hope the entire rest of the world has enough sense to follow me.